# ISV partners - Did you install the Environment Hub?

Tags: force.com, appexchange, isv

Can you share your experience on the purpose of "Environment Hub" ?

Will it replace the the LMA CRM that I am using to provision customers and manage leads?

Will it be an addition to the current LMA?

And most importantly, where should I install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the environment hub sooner or later since that's the new place where you'll create and manage your test and developer orgs. The hub comes with a lot of cool features and it's a really powerful tool, so I can only recommend it.

You will keep your LMA. The environment hub is a separate thing.

To install it I have raised a case to the support. If you are an ISV the can additionally activate enhanced features for org spinning and you'll get extra org types to create.

Comment: I did too, although where should it be installed? in the same place as the LMA on the CRM? in another DE org? Where do you plan to install it?

Comment: Usually the LMA org is a good choice. There are rare scenarios to install LMA and hub on different orgs (it's technically possible) but you go best to keep both on the same org. Typically it's on the EE org where they have provisioned the 2 free EE licenses.

Comment: Thanks! By the way my LMA also contains the Partner Ordering app, My only concern that "EU" app will not brake other functionalists